# How to setup debian/control to force updating a library?

Tags: ppa, dependencies, packaging

This question is **aimed at PPA/packages maintainers.**

I have a PPA with 2 packages:

- mypackage (currently version 1~ppa1~quantal)
- mypackagelib (currently version 1~ppa1~quantal)

Currently, the control file of mypackage has:

```
Depends: mypackagelib
```

I want to update the 2 packages to version '2' (mypackage version 2 and mypackagelib version 2).

**How can I make sure that the 2 packages will be updated when the user updates 'mypackage' ?**

FYI, changing the 'Depends' field to:

```
Depends: mypackagelib (>= 2)
```

does NOT work, and returns the following error:

```
mypackage : Depends: mypackagelib (>= 2) but mypackagelib-2~ppa1~quantal is to be installed
```

Comment: What's the version you set on mypackagelib? I think it needs to be mypackagelib_2 and not -2.

Comment: mfisch, thanks for looking at this. Please see comments below under Gilles's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version numbers are inconsistent. The order relation on version numbers is pretty complex. It is described in the [Debian policy manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version). In particular:

> First the initial part of each string consisting entirely of non-digit characters is determined. These two parts (one of which may be empty) are compared lexically. If a difference is found it is returned. The lexical comparison is a comparison of ASCII values modified so that all the letters sort earlier than all the non-letters and so that a tilde sorts before anything, even the end of a part. For example, the following parts are in sorted order from earliest to latest: ~~, ~~a, ~, the empty part, a.

In particular, `3.196~ppa1~quantal` is considered older than `3.196`. The typical use case for `~` is beta versions: `1.42~beta3` comes before `1.42`. You can check your understanding of Debian package version numbers by running `dpkg --compare-versions`:

```
$ dpkg --compare-versions '3.196~ppa1~quantal' '>=' '3.196'; echo $?
1
```

0 means that the order relation is met, 1 means that it isn't.

There is some incomplete advice on version numbers in the [PPA packaging help](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/BuildingASourcePackage). Since your package is not in Ubuntu, you don't need a `~` suffix; you should use a version number like `3.196ppa1`. The source dependency can be `(>= 3.196)` if any release of 3.196 will do, or something like `(>= 3.196ppa5)` if you need at least a certain package release.

If you keep the `~` in here, you must put it in the source dependency too: `(>= 3.196~ppa1~quantal)`. To say “at least the same version as the main package”, write

```
Depends: mypackagelib (>= ${binary:Version})
```

Another possibility ([thanks to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229725/how-to-setup-debian-control-to-force-updating-a-library/229749#comment284338_229749) [tumbleweed](https://askubuntu.com/users/32290/tumbleweed) is to declare a dependency on `3.196~` (the number and a tilde and nothing more), which is an older version than `3.196~anything`.

---

(This doesn't apply to you, but it might apply to future visitors. What follows applies when `libmypackage` contains a shared library (`.so`).)

The naming convention for libraries is `libmypackage1` and `libmypackage2`, by the way. If you started with `mypackagelib-1`, you should leave that, but switch to `libmypackage2` for the next version.

The two library packages `mypackagelib-1` and `mypackagelib-2` might coexist if there are programs still using the old library and programs using the new library installed at the same time. Unless the administrator has explicitly requested the installation of the library package (which he'd only do if he has a non-packaged program requiring the library, e.g. in `/usr/local`), the old library package will be marked as automatically installed, so it will be uninstalled automatically when there are no dependencies on it.

For more information on how to package a library, read the [Debian Library Packaging guide](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/column/libpkg-guide/libpkg-guide.html). Although Debian's policies are not mandatory for an Ubuntu PPA, it's a good idea to follow them: they illustrate best practice for working with Debian packaging tools.

Comment: Thanks Gilles, but this is not what i expected. I may have expressed myself the wrong way, i will improve my question to avoid confusion. When i wrote 'mypackagelib - 1', it stands for 'mypackagelib in version 1(~ppaXX)'. There is no package named 'mypackagelib-1' (nor 'mypackagelib-2'), only 'mypackagelib'. The package name does not change when upgrading version.

Comment: @LovinBuntu If the library package is still called `mypackagelib`, then `Depends: mypackagelib (>= 2)` is correct. You shouldn't do that for a package that contains a `.so`, as explained in the library packaging guide, so if your library is indeed a `.so`, you should switch to the `libmypackage2` naming. Since that's not working, there's still something that your obscuring of the name is hiding. Could you post the real package names and the unedited `control` file and error messages?

Comment: ok. The real name of `mypackage` is `boot-repair`. The real name of `mypackagelib` is `boot-sav`. The real current version is not `1~ppa1` but `3.197~ppa1`. The real new version is not `2~ppa1` but `3.198~ppa1`. The current packages can be found at https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/boot-repair/+packages , you will find the `control` in it. As you can see, there is no `.so`. And I confirm that (the equivalent of) `Depends: mypackagelib (>= 2)` does not work. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @LovinBuntu I wonder if this is related to the `~quantal` suffix. What exactly is the `Depends:` line in the `control` file (I only see 3.197 online), and the error message when trying to install? You may be interested in `dpkg --compare-versions` to check that your understanding of version numbers matches dpkg's.

Comment: I did the `(>= ..)` test in the `3.196~ppa3` version. See https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/boot-repair/+files/boot-repair_3.196%7Eppa3%7Eprecise.tar.gz . The control file had `Depends: boot-sav (>= 3.196)` . Some users reported `boot-repair : Depends: boot-sav (>= 3.196) but 3.196~ppa3~precise is to be installed`, some other users had `boot-repair : Depends: boot-sav (>= 3.196) but won't be installed`

Comment: `$ dpkg --compare-versions 3.196 le 3.196ppa3~quantal; echo $?
0` is ok, but:
`$ dpkg --compare-versions 3.196 le 3.196~ppa3~quantal; echo $?
1` fails. So I think the problem is either that dpkg doesn't handle the `~' correctly.... or that Launchpad should not use any '~' for the PPA's versioning. Anyway, i have no immediate workaround.

Comment: @LovinBuntu See my new answer. Please edit your question to match: the issue is the version number, and in particular the tildes.

Comment: thanks again! (BTW I am searching a sponsor.. see LP #806291 )

Comment: More practically, it's common to say `(>= 2~)`, when depending on a native package. This isn't a problem with non-native packages (packages with a `-` in the version)